# Multi-threading: dynamically create threads, call WS and report back for X number of tasks

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, web-services, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm new to multi-threading, so I need a general guidance how to proceed.

In a nutshell, I need to call an external webservice thousands of times per second. The response is roughly 1 second per record, which does not work well if I have a million of records to send. So, I've been tasked to use multi-threading to open multiple threads (the number is controlled dynamically) to simultaneously call WS. So, if I can open 100 threads that call WS simultaneously, the task should finish much faster... in theory.

Code is at the bottom, I've cut a lot of unnecessary pieces out of it so please let me know if something makes no sense

The idea behind this code is you would call in `Threads.Process`, pass `DataTable` with data that needs to be sent out via WS. This process would run until we processed all records in the data table and _threads (which holds a list of background objects currently working) has zero items in it.

`StartThreads` would instantiate new background objects if number of simultaneous threads permits and there is new data to be worked on. When a background object completes its task, in order to pass data back to the static object to log its data, it calls `Threads.ThreadFinished` and passes itself as parameter at which point logging info would be recorded and backgroundobject is removed from `_threads`.

However, during my testing I noticed that threads are overlaping when calling `Threads.ThreadFinished`, I tried to offset it with SyncLock to keep it thread safe, but it still does not work 100% fool proof (probably because there are other shared functions still not protected). Since I don't understand this threading very well, I have a feeling there is an easier way of doing this. So, am I on a right track? Should I keep going or switch to a different method? I've researched other multi-threading methods like ThreadPool, but I ended up with this method.

```
Public Class Threads
    Public Shared Sub ProcessRecords(ByVal dt As DataTable)
        _threads.Clear()
        _startTime = Now
        _dt = dt
        While Working()
            StartThreads()
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub StartThreads()
        While _threads.Count < Settings.NumberOfThreads AndAlso _rowCounter < _dt.Rows.Count
            Dim id As String = GetRandomChar(, 20)  ' Generate a random ID for logging purposes
            Dim tw As New ThreadWorker(_dt.Rows(_rowCounter), _rowCounter, id, _dt.Rows(_rowCounter)("id").ToString())
            _rowCounter += 1
            _threads.Add(tw)
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ThreadFinished(ByVal tw As ThreadWorker)
        SyncLock tw
            Log(tw.Log)
            _threads.Remove(tw)
        End SyncLock
        StartThreads()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function Working() As Boolean
        Return _rowCounter < _dt.Rows.Count OrElse _threads.Count > 0
    End Function
End Class


Public Class ThreadWorker
    Private _bw As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Private _logDebug As New StringBuilder

    Sub New(ByVal dr As DataRow)
        _bw = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler _bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_Working
        AddHandler _bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_Working(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        ' Call webservice ...
        _logDebug.AppendLine("Response from WS")
    End Sub

    Public Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        _logDebug.AppendLine("Job completed")
        Threads.ThreadFinished(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT 1:**
I think I've solved an issue with threads getting 'lost' - basically I have to `SyncLock _threads` in all `Shared` functions (`SyncLock tw` doesn't seem to do it's job). Still, this feels dirty and hacky at best. I feel like there is a better way to do things. I am currently looking into ThreadPool method, but I am a bit put off by its number of thread limits. I will potentially need to open thousands of threads.

What else I noticed is that the more concurrent threads I open, the longer it takes to get initial response from the WS. For example, if I work 1 record/thread at a time, it takes 1 second to get a response from WS. If I open 100 threads, it takes up to a minute to get a response. I suspect networking is buckling here, or maybe its a windows limitation?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  That would impact the available options.  e.g Maybe [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be a reasonable solution for .NET 4.5+?

Comment: .NET 3.5. I doubt I could use higher versions.